# Error with Closures: closure #1 in closure #2 in closure #1

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization, closures

I got a problem with swift cloures.

I am trying to just set a localized string to a variable on a Button press.

It works for simple strings as a parameter forthe formattet string, but not with variables.

The errors is as follows:

closure #1 in closure #2 in closure #1.

I've added a simplified example code:

```
...
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Button(action: {
                    self.searchQuery = ""
                    self.messageString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("example %@", comment: "example"), self.parameter)

                }) {
                    Text("Title")
                }
    }
}
```

thanks for your help in advance.

Alex

Comment: What are those properties, guessing a String var but that gives a completely different error?

Comment: the parameter is a simple integer variable in the struct.

Comment: I meant the ones you are updating, please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who has a similar problem, i foudn the solution.

The parameter for the format string, in my case an Int, has to be %d, not %@.

the variable to update is a string variable.